# checkout_cart_update_item_complete is not firing

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

**config.xml :-**

```
  <events>
  <checkout_cart_add_product_complete> 
    <observers>
      <checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler> 
        <type>model</type> 
        <class>observertest/observer</class> 
        <method>addToCartAdditionalItem</method>  
      </checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler>
    </observers>
  </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>

   <checkout_cart_update_item_complete> 
    <observers>
      <checkout_cart_update_item_handler> 
        <type>model</type> 
        <class>observertest/observer</class> 
        <method>updateCartItem</method>  
      </checkout_cart_update_item_handler>
    </observers>
  </checkout_cart_update_item_complete>
 </events>
```

In the events tag you can see 2 event in which first one(checkout_cart_add_product_complete) is working fine but second one is not.

Where i'm doing wrong, please let me know.

**Note:-**

I also tried to use **checkout_cart_update_items_after** instead of  **checkout_cart_update_item_complete** it's working fine but by using this event not getting updated cart total price (just getting old one). e.g- suppose before updating my cart if in my cart a product having 4 qty & it's subtotal is $80($20*4) & if i went to update  3 more qty(20*7=$140)  then this time by using event checkout_cart_update_items_after  i'm getting $80 on my event action(updateCartItem) but i want $140.

Thanks!!!

Comment: After a long afford, i got the solution.

I've used checkout_cart_save_after & it's working as per as my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`checkout_cart_update_item_complete` is dispatched in `Mage_Checkout_CartController::updateItemOptionsAction()` ... haven't testet it, but method description says:

```
/**
 * Update product configuration for a cart item
 */
public function updateItemOptionsAction()
```

I'm not sure if this is used only for configurable products. You can try `checkout_cart_update_items_after` instead.

It's dispatched in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::updateItems()` and should work for every cart update:

```
/**
 * Update cart items information
 *
 * @param   array $data
 * @return  Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
 */
public function updateItems($data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i already used checkout_cart_update_items_after & it's working fine but it's not fulfulling my requirement. i want to remove a specific product let's say X whenever cart value less than 100$ and add X whenever cart value atleast $100.

Comment: @wakarAhamad and it's not working? I use this in some of my extensions and I'm pretty sure that it works. You can add add a `Mage::log` in Mage.php `dispatchEvent` to check if this event is fired on your cart update action.

Comment: @wakarAhamad can you please add these information to your question? I've I working solution for it ... but no time at the moment. Will update my answer later.

Comment: I'm saying checkout_cart_update_items_after  it's working fine but by using this event not getting updated cart total price (just getting old one). e.g- suppose before updating my cart if in my cart a product having 4 qty & it's subtotal is $80($20*4) & if i went to update  3 more qty(20*7=$140)  then this time by using event checkout_cart_update_items_after  i'm getting $80 on my event action(updateCartItem) but i want $140.